# Frustrating issue with JavaScript's getElementById()

Tags: javascript, image-gallery, getelementbyid

This is the gallery I've been asked to implement

http://sandbox.leigeber.com/slideshow/

I've chopped and changed it ever so slightly so it'd fit into the new site's templating system a bit easier.

Whenever I run it, this line causes an error

```
ta=document.getElementById(thumbid);
```

Saying that `ta` is null. I know the thumbid var's value does exist as an Id of the unordered list.

I've tried to figure what's been going on for at least half an hour now, and can't seem to nail it!

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: the error i'm getting is `t = ta.getElementsByTagName('li');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah the code looks fine, and running the same lines from Firebug console work OK, so it makes me wonder if the `thumbs` element actually exists at the time of running? Is it in a `document.ready`-style handler? If it's being called before the element exists on that page, then `ta` will be null, which would create that error.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the slideshow function is called for initialization too early. This will be called before the DOM tree is ready:

```
var slideshow = function() {
 ...
} ();
```

try removing that () at the end.

Comment: I think this is correct.  The easiest solution might be to just move the script references to the bottom of the page, and leave them as-is.  That should improve the initial page load time too anyway.

Comment: Ah I missed the self running function parenthesis!

Answer (score 2):

Good news!  jQuery is written in vanilla Javascript!  You should be able to copy out their method for getting elements by ID and use that.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what value `thumbid` should have, but it looks to me like your problem is that the li items in your unordered list don't have `id`s, they have `value`s.

Calling `document.getElementById('thumbs')` works fine to get the `ul` element of the list itself.

Answer (score 0):

In Safari 4 line 19 was throwing me a type error regarding `ta` which was `null`.
This is due to the line you pointed out where `ta` was assigned.

I like how you encapsulate the functions in a closure, but I think the `window.onload` can be changed to be more [jQuery like](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/ready#fn); the same can be said of actually [selecting the elements](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors) you're looking for, something like `t=$('ul#thumbs li')` should do the trick. I don't know if throwing a `var` in front of `ta` is going to fix anything, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: If I use a jQuery selector though, will the native JS methods work on the jQuery object returned? I don't believe so....